# Comprobar múltiplo de 2 y valores de array

Tags: java, eclipse, bucle-for, depuración

Me surge una pregunta haciendo lo siguiente. ¿De qué manera podría comprobar que los valores de los parámetros son correctos?

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    try {
        //Comprobar multiplo de 2   
        if (Integer.parseInt(args[i]) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("El valor " + args[i] + " Son múltiplos");
        } else {
            System.out.println("El valor " + args[i] + " No son múltiplos");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("El valor " + args[i] + " No son múltiplos");
    }
}

//Valores corectos.
List valores = new ArrayList<String>();
valores.add("-e");
valores.add("firefox");

//Comprobar valores correctos de parametros
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Valor " + valores.get(i) + " es correcto? " + valores.get(i).equals(args[i]));
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Como determinas si los parámetros "e" y "-firefox" serían correctos?

Comment: Primero no puedes convertir a Int una cadena, por lo tanto estos valores se considerarían como "No múltiplos". Con respecto a la comparación, puedes usar un bucle que compara los valores almacenados en args[], revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para determinar si un valor valor es múltiplo de 2, es precisamente como lo realizas (`numero % 2 ==0`), pero en este caso, al ingresar argumentos que no son numéricos y tratar de convertirlos mediante `Integer.parseInt(...)` obtendrías el error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

para este caso agrega un manejo de excepcion el cual describa que el valor no es múltiplo de 2:

```
try {
    //Comprobar multiplo de 2   
    if (Integer.parseInt(args[0]) % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Son múltiplos");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No son múltiplos");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("No son múltiplos");
}
```

En cuanto a la comprobación puedes realizar un List donde almacenes los valores correctos y puedas compararlos mediante .equals() si tienen el mismo valor:

```
//Valores corectos.
List valores = new ArrayList<String>();
valores.add("-e");
valores.add("firefox");

//Comprobar valores correctos de parametros
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Valor " + valores.get(i) + " es correcto? " + valores.get(i).equals(args[i]));
}
```

---

Este sería el código completo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        try {
            //Comprobar multiplo de 2   
            if (Integer.parseInt(args[i]) % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("El valor " + args[i] + " Son múltiplos");
            } else {
                System.out.println("El valor " + args[i] + " No son múltiplos");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("El valor " + args[i] + " No son múltiplos");
        }
    }

    //Valores corectos.
    List valores = new ArrayList<String>();
    valores.add("-e");
    valores.add("firefox");

    //Comprobar valores correctos de parametros
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Valor " + valores.get(i) + " es correcto? " + valores.get(i).equals(args[i]));
    }

}
```